# why do minus(negative) values work with index?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jquery and basically , i decided to put Jquery to some practical use and so i build the following script :

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('keydown', checkey);

    var index = 0,
        $items = $('ul li a');


    function checkey(e) {

        // console.log($items);    

        if (e.which == 38) {
            // key up
            index -= 1;
        };
        if (e.which == 40) {
            //key down
            index += 1;
        }

        console.log(index);

        $items.eq(index).trigger('focus');
    }


});
```

useing this script you can navigate your menu useing the up and down arrow keys .

the fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/owxebeue/). now i have one question about the code that i have used , in particular the below line of code:

```
$items.eq(index).trigger('focus');
```

now, the index variable is incremented and decremented in my script, but when i keep pressing keyup, and the index keep decrementing and goes below 0 I.E. -1 , -2 , -3 , -4 ... etc , `$items.eq(index).trigger('focus');`, this line still works , i was't expecting it to work with negative values , i was expecting it only to work from 0-4 .

so how and why do negative values work with the below statement :

```
eg. $items.eq(-2).trigger('focus'); ??
```

**NOTE :** in the fiddle please check the console and experiment with arrow up and arrow down, to understand what i am talking about .

Comment: Try reading the manual!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [jQuery API documentation](https://api.jquery.com/eq/):

> Providing a negative number indicates a position starting from the end of the set, rather than the beginning.